Current source with low drop out voltage
I am using this circuit to provide 10mA for some LEDs connected in series.
It regulates fine, but the problem is that the voltage drop is about ~3V, meaning that I cannot connect more LEDs or, I have to increase the power supply. Actually, our customer just decreased the power supply from 24V to 12V and we need to adapt.
My worst case requirement (over temp) is VSINK = 9.75V and I have only 9V (due to 3V dropped).
One solution that comes into my mind is to duplicate this design and re-arrange LEDs to balance them through those 2 separate current sources. Is there a simpler solution around, or should I consider a re-design everything with a OPAMP.


Do you have any requirements regarding temperature stability, or absolute minimum or maximum output current over temperature?  The circuit Andy posted is a classic, but it does drift a bit because the Q2 Vbe decreases with temperature increases.

No particular, need to be around 10mA over -40/+85 with 10..15% accuracy. We say to use series configuration to save power in initial 24V design, for each one needed a big resistor in parallel.

Here is a simple circuit that has about a 150mV dropout voltage, very accurate current, and is not much different in cost than yours.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Maybe add a 1kΩ base resistor to limit the base current if the LEDs are disconnected.

Here is the circuit 'reversed' using a low-voltage (affordable) RRIO op-amp. The power supply for the op-amp is derived from the reference.


Thanks Sphero. I need source, not sink, I will try to reverse yours and simulate. And YES, I have a use case with no LED's (disconnected).

Reversing it requires an op-amp with input range that includes the positive rail, so it would likely have to be a RRIO type, so not as cheap.

TL072 is cheap and its input range includes positive rail, but not negative rail, and its output range does not include positive rail... but if you use a TL072 and a high Vgsth MOSFET as pass device, the MOSFET's threshold should shift voltage enough so TL072 operates within spec

I just simulated this circuit and I think is NOT suited for my use case (low currents, 10mA). This is because for low drop out, keeping RE ~ 10 Ohms, VREF approaches VDD rail and this will make LM358 goes crazy :)) need a expensive one with rail to rail inputs :))) But thanks anyhow!

ooo.. clever how to power the MCP :)))) Do you have a reliable model of this MCP to be simulated in LtSpice? Usually, MCHIP models are not working in LtSpice.

@bobflux  I know they'll work typically, but I see things like this datasheet 6.8 showing worst-case input common mode range +/-11V with +/-15V supplies.  A mistake?

@user1797147 That  one works fine. The model is in the ZZZ folder, so from Bordodynov's collection. R1 also limits the base current, so no need for a base resistor.

to be honest, works perfect, I just simulated with AD8544 from ADI models. I will give you the credits because fulfills all that I asked for :)))) But because it's cheaper and don't need that accuracy, I will use Andy's circuit. Thanks both!

@user1797147 yes, the two-transistor circuit is more popular for good reason. The dropout is maybe 0.8V or 0.9V vs. 0.15V but when you get to that level you're worrying about temperature coefficients of the LEDs and tolerance of the 12V supply.

Vref on the AZ431L (U11) is 1.25 volts and this sets the voltage across the 120 Ω resistor to be equal to 1.25 volts hence, you have already lost 1.25 volts in your design. Then you have the forward base-emitter voltage of the BJT (Q2) which is usually taken to be around 0.7 volts. That means a running total of around 2 volts dropped across U11 and Q2's base-emitter region. Added to this is the voltage dropped across R1 in supplying base current into Q2.
This accounts for another 1 volt because 1 volt divided by 10 kΩ is 100 μA and, that's about the current needed into the base to have 10 mA flowing from Q2's emitter (a current gain of 100).
But, you could use a BJT instead of the AZ431L and sacrifice a bit of accuracy in the current for a lower equivalent reference voltage (0.7 volts). Then you could reduce the 10 kΩ resistor to say 2 kΩ and gain a bit more headroom using something like this circuit: -

Image from Constant current LED driver using transistors (another post on SE). It shows the LED(s) on the top side of the supply (and this may be an option for you to consider) but, it can be made to work effectively with the LED string on the lower side but why bother when the above will work well in your scenario. R2 would be about 70 Ω.
It works well because you can set the input to the positive supply rail and not incur any volt drop across R1 that would eat into your supply voltage for the LED. I'm sure if you simulated it you would see the benefit.
High-side current limiter (using PNP transistors) from Current Limiting Circuits: -


Thanks Andy. I need source not sink, but I will try to reverse this configuration you posted.

Swap the transistors for PNP types and you should be good to go @user1797147

I will try to use this one, the most simpler for what I need :)))

You can get almost the full 12V compliance voltage, a little over 11V in fact, with a two-transistor constant current source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Current is set by R1:
$$ I_{OUT}  \approx \frac{0.7V}{R_1} $$
0.7V is lost across sense resistor R1, and at least 0.2V between Q2's collector and emitter, but the remaining 11.1V can be made available to the load if needed, as shown left. On the right I have fewer LEDS, requiring less compliance voltage from the source, but current remains 10mA or so.
